# What exactly are the objects returned by openCL functions ?

Tags: object, opencl

In OpenCl there are many calls like this that create objects

> clCreateProgramWithSource Creates a program object for a context, and
>   loads the source code specified by the text strings in the strings
>   array into the program object.

My question is what exactly is this object, as an object in Computer Science has [many definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29)?

I want to understand at lower level what exactly happens to the source code string and what exactly is program object, and what it contains?

Answer (score 0):

In this case object means an instance of a `cl_program` structure. However, from the OpenCL header `cl.h`:

```
typedef struct _cl_program *        cl_program;
```

cl_program is just a pointer to an `_cl_program` structure. Why? OpenCL is an open standard and all implementations are subject to the specific library developers, who implement the standard for specific hardware (e.g., Intel CPUs).

Comment: Is it possible to see the content of the struct? Or is it in binary form?

Comment: They residesvin binary form within the compiled libraries. If you seek general guidiance look at on of the open source implementations.

Answer (score 0):

It is implementation defined and there are no structures declared for you to inspect them.

On a given implementation, these handles might be pointers to internally defined structures, or they could be indexes into a collection of such items. You don't know, and if you figure it out, it could change in a driver update. That's why they are opaque types, so the implementation can do whatever it likes inside and just return a handle to your code.